# Why can't I add these two strings together?

Tags: applescript-objc

```
on oneButtonClicked_(sender)
    set faceNumber's setStringValue() to faceNumber's stringValue() & "1"
end oneButtonClicked_
```

I get this error: "Can’t make «class ocid» id «data optr000000000058B37BFF7F0000» into type list, record or text. (error -1700)"

faceNumber is a label and when the user clicks the button, I want to add string of "1" to it. So for example, if the user clicked the button 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stringValue returns an <strike>NSString</strike>*(wrong answer)* **CFString**. You have to make a real AppleScript String to use it.
BTW your code `set faceNumber's setStringValue()` is not correct. The reasons are:

1. The Cocoa handlers are always using the underscore.
2. If you use the setter `setStringValue()` you don't need to use `set x to`
3. If you want to use `setStringValue()` you must give the parameter between the parentheses

Now put everything together:

```
on oneButtonClicked_(sender)
    faceNumber's setStringValue_((faceNumber's stringValue) as string & "1")
end oneButtonClicked_
```

or (to have it clearer):

```
on oneButtonClicked_(sender)
    tell faceNumber
        set currentValue to (its stringValue) as string
        setStringValue_(currentValue & "1")
    end tell
end oneButtonClicked_
```

I hope you like the answer, after pressing the button twice you have an 11 at the end of the label.

Cheers, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thanks! So when I have an NSString, I have to convert it to an AppleScript string to use it?

Comment: In fact you get a CFString (my answer is wrong at this point) and have to convert it to an AppleScript string.